# Unknown Apple TV showing up in system audio menu

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, appletv

When opening the volume control / audio menu in the system menu bar I sometimes see "Apple TV" among the possible audio sinks. I don't own an Apple TV nor does one exist on my network so I'm assuming it's detecting a neighbor's device using Bluetooth. I've selected it twice accidentally while typing this.

The device also shows up in the display selection menu. I guess it will ask me for a verification code if I select it, but it's kind of uncomfortable to feel like I could start broadcasting my screen at any time by mistake (even if it isn't possible).

Is it possible to make macOS (10.14.3) stop displaying devices I don't own and aren't paired with?

Comment: Try the answers in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/90888/88313).  It's similar but not a duplicate to your issue.

Comment: @fsb That isn't going to be helpful. Apple TV discovery works over 802.11, not Bluetooth.

Comment: @duskwuff It seems that you're right about that, I made the wrong assumption. I don't know why I didn't just turn off bluetooth and check... yes, the device is still there.